# How to increment a value in a loop in elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to count how many times a number there are in each range from range1 to range4. Range 1 is 1-10, range 2 is 11-20, range 3 is 21-30, and range 4 is 31-40. What I have below is:

```
range1=0
range2=0
range3=0
range4=0
arr=[1,11,2,22,33,23]
Enum.each arr, fn(x) ->
  if x >=1 and x<=10 do
    range1=range1+1
  end
  if x>=11 and x<=20 do
    range2=range2+1
  end
  if x>=21 and x<=30 do
    range3=range3+1
  end
  if x>=31 and x<=40 do
    range4=range4+1
  end
end 

IO.puts range1
IO.puts range2
IO.puts range3
IO.puts range4
```

However when I run it, it'll say that they're all 0. Why is it doing that?

Comment: As Aleksei details below - you need to radically change programming idiom to benefit from Elixir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is an immutable language. One cannot *change* the value of a variable. Ever.

One might *rebind* a variable, but it would never leak to the outer scope, so what are you doing is basically binding `rangeN`  in an internal scope to immediately discard it. The variable (having the same name by coincidence) from the outer scope never gets changed.

We don’t have *loops* in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) either. We use map/reduce instead.

That said, what you need is [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)

```rb
Enum.reduce(
    [1,11,2,22,33,23], # input
    {0, 0, 0, 0},      # initial accumulator
    fn x, {acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4} ->
  cond do
    x>=1 and x<=10 -> {acc1 + 1, acc2, acc3, acc4}
    x>=11 and x<=20 -> {acc1, acc2 + 1, acc3, acc4}
    x>=21 and x<=30 -> {acc1, acc2, acc3 + 1, acc4}
    x>=31 and x<=40 -> {acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4 + 1}
  end
end)
#⇒ {2, 1, 2, 1}
```

The function always returns the result of the last expression, hence we are to use `cond/1` here. But the idiomatic way would be to have multiple clauses of the accumulating function with guards.

```rb
Enum.reduce [1,11,2,22,33,23], {0, 0, 0, 0}, fn 
  x, {acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4} when x>=1 and x<=10 ->
    {acc1 + 1, acc2, acc3, acc4}
  x, {acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4} when x>=11 and x<=20 ->
    {acc1, acc2 + 1, acc3, acc4}
  x, {acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4} when x>=21 and x<=30 ->
    {acc1, acc2, acc3 + 1, acc4}
  x, {acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4} when x>=31 and x<=40 ->
    {acc1, acc2, acc3, acc4 + 1}
end
```

---

To get to the values one might either pattern match the result or use [`Kernel.elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2).

```rb
{less_that_10, _, _, _} =
  Enum.reduce(...)
less_than_10
#⇒ 2

input
|> Enum.reduce(...)
|> elem(0)
#⇒ 2
```

Comment: How can I access the value of acc1 after its been changed?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question. Assign the value to a local variable, perhaps.

Comment: So what I wanted to do after was, I want to print the new value of acc1, which would now be 2

Comment: After reduce is done, or each time it gets increased?

Comment: Pattern match the result or use `|> elem(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

> when I run it, it'll say that they're all 0. Why is it doing that?

Variables in Elixir are bound to the current scope. If you bind to a variable inside a function (such as the anonymous function you passed to `Enum.each/2` in your code), that variable is only available inside that function. Although you assign to `range1` inside the anonymous function, that's a completely different variable to the `range1` you defined at the top of the file, which is always `0`.

> How to increment a value in a loop in elixir

This is the wrong way of thinking about it. What you need to think about is *processing lists*. For your case, I think combining [`Enum.frequencies_by/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies_by/2) with [guards](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/patterns-and-guards.html#guards) and [ranges](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Range.html) is a good solution:

```elixir
Enum.frequencies_by([1, 11, 2, 22, 33, 23], fn
  i when i in 1..10 -> :range1
  i when i in 11..20 -> :range2
  i when i in 21..30 -> :range3
  i when i in 31..40 -> :range4
end)
```

This produces:

```elixir
%{range1: 2, range2: 1, range3: 2, range4: 1}
```

Comment: `Enum.frequencies_by([1, 11, 2, 22, 33, 23], &div(&1, 10))
#⇒ %{0 => 2, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 1}` :)

Comment: We also can have a macro that gets ranges and produces the clauses in compile-time :))

Answer (score 1):

If I could make the assumption that your ranges are fixed, and that your inputs are greater than zero, I propose this solution:

```
[range1,range2,range3,range4] =
   for elem <- arr, reduce: [0,0,0,0] do
     answer -> 
       update_in(answer, [Access.at!(div((elem - 1), 10))], &(&1 + 1))
   end
```

[Access.at!()](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html#at!/1) conveniently will throw an exception for indices outside of the range of the output array.  In other words, an input of 45 will generate an index of 4, which is outside of the range of indices for [0,0,0,0]